# How to format a Ajax datatable column value?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a table that is generated with datatable plugin. This table is populated with an Ajax result. Its working fine but the problem is the data is not well formatted and I want the price to have a uniform four figures after decimal point.

I am doing this inside WordPress.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  var url = window.location.href;
  var Id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);

    jQuery('#ppViewHistoryPage').DataTable( {
      ajax: {
          url: 'https://mobile.premiumpension.com/multichannel/api/Prices/GetFundPriceByDateRange?fundId='+Id+'&startDate=2014-1-1&endDate=2050-1-1',
          dataSrc: 'result'
      },
      "columns": [
    {"data": "FundName"},
    {"data": "ValueDate"},
    {"data": "UnitPrice"},
  ]
  });

  })
```

I have checked the datatable documentation but there I can't figure out how to format 
[image]

Comment: Use `render` format for values in `datatable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Jquery Code

```
{
    "data": "ValueDate",
    "render": function (data) {
        var date = new Date(data);
        return  date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-"+ date.getDate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, bro :)